# SQL syntax to look for a specific figure among a number in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, sql-like

I'm looking for, how to search for a specific digit inside a numeric column in Teradata. I managed to do it for char type with

```
SELECT * from Table WHERE CharColumn LIKE ('%SearchedChar%')
```

but it doesn't seem to work with numeric values.
Thanks for your help.

**EDIT** :
I need this because i'm coding a .NET function to generate teradata queries from what a user types in a textbox.

Comment: Cast/convert to char, and do LIKE. But why do you want to do this?

Comment: can u tell, what numeric condition u want to apply?

Comment: @jarlh can't i just do like this : LIKE ('% CAST(myNumber as CHAR) %') ? Because i need to do it in a single query. I don't know how to CAST and then do LIKE

Comment: Why don't you try and see? (The best way to learn SQL is by trying all kinds of constructions!)

Comment: @jarlh LIKE ('%'+ (CAST(myNumber AS CHAR))+'%') throws the following error : "Partial string matching requires character operands. ". It seems the cast is failing somehow

Comment: Maybe I'm dense, but I don't understand what you're asking. Please post an example what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE ('%'+ (CAST(myNumber AS CHAR))+'%')` is SQL Server syntax, of course this fails in Teradata :-)

`+` is a numeric operator in Standard SQL while `||` concatenates strings:

```
WHERE CharColumn LIKE '%' || CAST(myNumber AS CHAR) || '%'
```

Of course searching for a digit within a number indicates a wrong datatype...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `convert` function, but as mentioned below:

```
Declare @Digit int = 9 --Digit that you want to search

SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10), NumColumn) LIKE ('%'+ CONVERT(varchar(10), @Digit) +'%')
```

Comment: What does your NumColumn stand for ?

Comment: I get an error :
 "Datatype 'myNumColumn' does not match a defined type name. "

Comment: **1.** `NumColumn` is your column of `int` datatype; replace it with your required column name like : `charColumn`. **2.** If `myNumColumn` is of datatype `varchar()`, then no need to convert! Let me know...!